# no puedo guardar información enviada desde un formulario LaravelCollective en mi Base de Datos

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

El Problema es que antiguamente usaba un formulario en html con bootstrap y funcionaba correctamente, pero desidi usar LaravelCollective para reemplazar el formulario de HTML por el de LaravelCollective y visualmente no hubo problemas pero al momento de guardar información me lanza un error, a continuacion describire todo por pasos.

**Formulario HTML**

```
<form class="form-group" method="post" action="/trainers" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Slug</label>
        <input type="text" name="slug" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Avatar</label>
        <input type="file" name="avatar">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Descripcion</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="des"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

**Controlador**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // este if verifica si existe una imagen 
    if ($request->hasFile('avatar')){ //verifica si es una archivo
        $file=$request->file('avatar'); //guarda la imagen en la varible $file
        $name=time().$file->getClientOriginalName(); // se le asigna un nombre a la imagen unico
        $file->move(public_path().'/images/',$name); // se mueve la imagen a una carpea llamada images
    }

        $trainer=new Trainer();
        $trainer->name=$request->input('name'); // almacena el nombre en trainer
        $trainer->avatar=$name; // se asocia la imagen con el nombre del entrenador
        $trainer->des=$request->input('des'); // almacena la descripcion
        $trainer->slug=$request->input('slug');
        $trainer->save();
        return 'Saved';
}
```

------------------------ Hasta aqui Funciona Todo Bien ------------------------

Cuando paso el formulario de HTML a LaravelCollective hago lo siguiente

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'trainers.store','method'=>'POST','file'=>true]) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('name','Nombre') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('slug','Slug') !!}
        {!! Form::text('slug',null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('avatar','Avatar') !!}
        {!! Form::file('avatar')!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('des','Descripcion') !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('des',null,['class'=>'form-control','rows'=>'5'])!!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::submit('Guardar',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Visualmente hace lo mismo pero el problema se presenta en el controlador que use anteriormente, me da un error que me dice **"Undefined variable: name"**. al ver la interfaz de Laravel para los errores me doy cuenta que los datos llegan al controlador mas no se guardan por este detalle.

He buscado a que se debe el problema pero hasta ahora no he tenido exito si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradesere .

**Version de laravel que uso es la 5.6 
Version de LaravelCollective 5.4**

Comment: Dices que los datos llegan al controlador, ¿entonces en qué línea está el error?

Comment: el error se presenta en la linea $trainer->avatar=$name; que dice que no esta definida la variable $name, cosa que si lo esta en el if

Comment: Pues si supieras que con ese mismo controlador cuando uso el formulario de HTML si guarda los datos de manera correcta y al usar LaravelCollective no, lo que hace es lanzar un error tal cual sino no entrara en el if y no se guardara nada en la variable $name

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema es que no estas especificando el atributo de forma correcta:

Trata cambiando `file` por `files`, [aquí](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#opening-a-form) la documentación.

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'trainers.store','method'=>'POST','files'=>true]) !!}
```

PS: Antes de realizar este cambio, en tu controlador ejecuta un `dd($request->all())` y verifica que este llegando toda la información, incluyendo el archivo.

Comment: deberías agregar como referencia el enlace a la documentación, por que si efectivamente tiene el nombre mal escrito https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#opening-a-form

Comment: Ya lo agregue @element gracias!

Comment: Utilice el dd($request->all()) para verificar que esten llegando los datos y pues para mi sorpresa con este formulario de LaravelCollective no me llega al controlador cosa que  si hace con HTML

Comment: Perdonen me equivoque en el comentario pasado si estan llegando la informacion al controlador al utilizar return $request->all(); me refleja toda la informacion que deseo, mas parece ser que no entra en el IF

Answer (score 0):

Bueno por fin di con la solución a este enigma y era que al momento de seleccionar la imagen el nombre de esta no debe tener espacios en blanco, por alguna razón la imagen no se carga en la condición, eso era todo probé con ambos formularios y funciono bien gracias a todos por ayudarme.